# Adding different links to Javascript created elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm still trying to get to grips with JQuery and want to create what is essentially a REALLLY simple 'game'

The idea is to have a bunch of moving images on a background and each image will link to a separate web page.

But I'm struggling to find a way to make each separate moving image have a different hyperlink.

This is my JS so far...

```
            $(document).ready(function () {
            newDiv();
            newDiv();
            newDiv();
            newDiv();
            newDiv();
            newDiv();
        });

        function newDiv() {
            var $div = $("<div class='a'><a href='https://soundcloud.com/alcopop/sets/tellison-live-on-the-alcopopacruiser/s-hjXnt'>");
            $(".animatedDivs").append($div);
            animateDiv();



            function animateDiv() {
                var newq = makeNewPosition();
                var oldq = $div.offset();
                var speed = calcSpeed([oldq.top, oldq.left], newq);

                $div.animate({
                    top: newq[0],
                    left: newq[1]
                }, speed, function () {
                    animateDiv();
                });

            };
        }

        function makeNewPosition() {

            // Get viewport dimensions (remove the dimension of the div)
            var h = 500-80;
            var w = $(window).width() - 80;

            var nh = Math.floor(Math.random() * h);
            var nw = Math.floor(Math.random() * w);

            return [nh, nw];

        }

        function calcSpeed(prev, next) {

            var x = Math.abs(prev[1] - next[1]);
            var y = Math.abs(prev[0] - next[0]);

            var greatest = x > y ? x : y;

            var speedModifier = .4;

            var speed = Math.ceil(greatest / speedModifier);

            return speed;

        }
```

And a link to what I've done so far...

https://jsfiddle.net/5vgtx2d3/2/

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call `newDiv()` with a link, you can do:

```
    function newDiv( newLink ) {
        var $div = "<div class='a'><a href='" + newLink + "'>";
        $(".animatedDivs").append($div);
        animateDiv();
        ....
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try passing the link as an argument in the newDiv() function

```
newDiv('your link');
```

Then you can use it like this

```
function newDiv(link) {
            var $div = $("<div class='a'><a href='"+link+"'>");
            $(".animatedDivs").append($div);
            animateDiv();



            function animateDiv() {
                var newq = makeNewPosition();
                var oldq = $div.offset();
                var speed = calcSpeed([oldq.top, oldq.left], newq);

                $div.animate({
                    top: newq[0],
                    left: newq[1]
                }, speed, function () {
                    animateDiv();
                });

            };
        }
```